# Why is my NAA flag disputed?

Tags: support, not-an-answer

So I got [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26866080/3714930) in the Late Answers review queue. To me this looks like a **Thanking the posters** answer, as described in [When to flag an answer as “it is not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/3714930) so I flagged it as not an answer.

Now I see the flag was disputed, but I don't understand why. As I see it, this answer says: 'I had this same problem but now it works thanks to the other answer' and has some of his code which now works. It even literally says:

> i had the same error but now works (thanks Jane!)

As far as I can see, that's not an attempt to answer the question, so why was my flag disputed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It not only says

> i had the same error but now works (thanks Jane!)

but it also shows the used solution. That makes it an answer to the question. The OP had the same problem used some of the code from the self-answered question of the OP and gave back his full implementation to the community.

Maybe that answer doesn't add much, maybe a downvote is OK-ish but flagging as NAA is wrong in this case.

Your flag was marked invalid by some users correctly.

Do notice that [disputed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag) means that some users agreed with your flag and some didn't.

On the risk of not longer answering the question, by adding to much context, this doesn't mean that everybody should post his own code including the solution. Such answers can be downvoted: *this answer is not useful* (because it adds nothing new to the specific problem in the question)

Comment: But the question was already answered (by the OP). So what does adding his own code, which uses the solution from the accepted answer, do to answer the question? As I see it, the solution he shows is an answer to *his own* question, not to the question to which he added it.

Comment: If a question is already answered doesn't care. It doesn't add much which why I suggest downvoting. And he might answer his own question but I can't tell but he offers with his post more context (still his own but I don't care).

Comment: So it offers more context, but does that answer the question?

Comment: For me it does...

Comment: Ok, then that's where we disagree. I think that if everyone who uses an answer on SO would post his own implementation of the solution as a new answer, SO would quickly become cluttered with 'context'

Comment: You're free to downvote such answers, as the downvote button says:'this answer is not useful'

Comment: I will. Thanks for the explanation.